# If app is idle till 10 minutes, how to start from splash screen

Tags: javascript, cordova

I want to write javascript code through which a Phonegap app get restarted when it is on idle state till last 10-20 minutes. I am using following code

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var idleTime = 0;
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000);

    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
    });

    $(this).scroll(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
    });

    function timerIncrement() {

        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime > 10) { // 20 minutes
            window.localStorage.removeItem("user_id");
            window.localStorage.removeItem("client_id");
            location.reload();
        }
     }
 });
```

Comment: I have also used navigator.app.exitApp() . But it close the app not start from splash screen.

Comment: try navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", {wait:2000, loadingDialog:"Wait,Loading App", loadUrlTimeoutValue: 60000});

Comment: or make a fake splashscreen using html in your app, and after 10minute refresh the app and show that div

Comment: @Hiero: I tryed navigator.app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", {wait:2000, loadingDialog:"Wait,Loading App", loadUrlTimeoutValue: 600}); But did not show splash screen. This code only load my index.html file. I want splash screen then index.html page.

Answer (score 1):

To show the splash screen again you can use

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
```

But you will have to hide it with code too

```
setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi jcesarmobile, When I am trying to add splashscreen plugin using cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen command, I am getting error message "Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 3.5.0, failed version requirement: >=3.6.0". Please suggest what to do?

Comment: Update your cordova cli and cordova android project version

Answer (score 0):

Use this event to write a sleep time value to local storage

```
document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Use this event to check the sleep time value when your app is restarting to determine whether it's been more than 10 mins

```
document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Use the code below to show and hide your splashscreen if your criteria is met

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
setTimeout(function() {
   navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 3000);
```

Se event details in the [cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html)